# How to used `Class<T>` with a child class, where T is the parent class

Tags: java, oop

Suppose I have the following setup

```
public class Parent{

}

public class Child1 extends Parent{

}

public class Child2 extends Parent{

}
```

I can do the following

```
Class<Parent> test = Parent.class
```

But the following gives me an error.

```
Class<Parent> test = Child1.class
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `Class<? extends Parent>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    Class<? extends Parent> test1 = Child1.class;
```

Comment: oh, umm, there we go :)

Answer (score 1):

Others already said that

```
Class<? extends Parent> test1 = Child1.class;
```

is the solution.

So now the question may arise why

```
Class<Parent> test1 = Child1.class;
```

didn't work in the first place? Or, let me phrase it differently, why any `Generic<T>` only works for exactly `T` and not its subclasses?

Well, that has to do with what can you do with that. Imagine a class like

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T content
    public void accept(T stuff) { content = stuff; }
    public void accept(Supplier<T> stuff) { content = stuff.get(); }
    public T get() { return content; }
    public void put(Consumer<T> c) { c.put(content); }
}
```

Now we use that and expect `Generic<Number>` to work properly and in both directions:

```
Supplier<Integer> si = () -> 42;
Supplier<Number> sn = () -> 42;
Consumer<Integer> ci = n -> System.out.println(c);
Consumer<Number> cn = n -> System.out.println(c);

Generic<Integer> gi = new Generic<Integer>();
Generic<Number> gn = new Generic<Number>();

gi.accept(si); // works
gi.accept(sn); // won't work (1), that's ok
gi.put(ci); // works
gi.put(cn); // won't work (2), but should

gn.accept(si); // won't work (3), but should
gn.accept(sn); // works
gn.put(ci); // won't work (4), that's ok
gn.put(cn); // works
```

If the type system would allow combining everything, then all of (1) (2) (3) (4) would work and that would be too tolerant. So you have to explicitly state the direction you want it to work, to be tolerant:

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T content
    public void accept(T stuff) { content = stuff; }
    public void accept(Supplier<? extends T> stuff) { content = stuff.get(); }
    public T get() { return content; }
    public void put(Consumer<? super T> c) { c.put(content); }
}
```

Now, `accept()` accepts everything that provides a `T` or subclasses, and `put()` accepts everything that accepts a `T` or superclasses.

This way,

```
gi.put(cn); // (2)
gn.accept(si); // (3)
```

both work (`gi.put()` accepting a `Consumer<Number>` and `gn.accept()` accepting a `Supplier<Integer>`), while

```
gi.accept(sn); // still won't work (1), that's ok
gn.put(ci); // still won't work (4), that's ok
```

don't work, as there are compatibility issues with assignments.